# Automapper and enum property

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, automapper

I am wondering where should I define enum if we have a multi-layered architecture and classes with this enum property or field (Domain, DTO, ViewModel)? Inside the POCO classes or outside, in every layer we need to repeat this code or not etc?

Answer (score 4):

we use the Domain, DTO, ViewModel... layered architecture and when we define enums that need to be used across layers, we define them in the DTO layer only. This is because the DTO layer is, by definition, accessible to all layers. We use the standard of creating such shared enums outside classes which makes for better readability (i.e. EnumName.EnumValue vs ClassName.EnumName.EnumValue), but I guess that's a matter of preference.

Comment: hmm...does the data access layer knows about business layer? is it right solution?

Comment: I would expect your DTO layer to be pretty generic definitions in between layers specific to data and view. Seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Our data access services return DTO objects (and yes they are meant to be generic, i.e. no data layer elements and no view layer elements), and as a rule the business layer communicates purely in DTO objects.

Comment: @sergio as I know if I have 3 layers DAL, BLL and Some View Layer, they will depend from each other only in down-top style (means that BLL depends on DAL and View depends on BLL and it means that DAL knows nothing about BLL) am I right?

Comment: That sounds right. DTO = Data Transfer Object, so in our world, the DTO layer holds classes and enums that define objects used to communicate across layers. BLL calls DAL and DAL returns DTO objects. If any input parameters are required by DAL methods, the parameters are also DTO objects or primitives. Same is true for View Layer to BLL communication. We also allow for View layer to DAL communication but again, only using DTOs.  DTO objects are the agreed upon communication "language"  between layers.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do NOT repeat the code as that could result in discrepancies and hard to find bugs. My recommendation would be to place such things in a commonly referenced DLL assembly so that it can be used by any of your other application layers without introducing additional dependencies.

Comment: DRY principle?)

Answer (score 0):

Personally i define in a separated file, so for example if a have the enum "Bla", that would be defined in the "Bla.cs" an any code that use that enum would use an "using" directive. But that is totally optional, what defines where a enum can be accessed is the namespace, so:

1. if you define in the namespace "Application" you access it by `Application.Bla` or just by "Bla" when in the same namespace
2. if you define inside a class named "Aclass" as long you define it as public you can access it by `Aclass.Bla`